# Plotly sankey diagram does not follow x position specified by argument in R

Tags: r, plotly, sankey-diagram

I have `nodes` and `links` data frames to plot `sankey` diagram with `plot_ly` in `r`.

```
nodes <- data.frame(
  name = c(
    "st_con_rt/main-room", "st_con_rt/sub-room", "st_con_tr/direct",
    "st_con_tr/terrace", "st_adsb/add", "st_adsb/sub", "st_th/hira",
    "st_th/tsuma", "tr_adsb/add", "tr_adsb/sub", "st_sub_main_th/hira",
    "st_sub_main_th/other", "st_sub_main_th/tsuma", "st_sub2_main_th/hira",
    "st_sub2_main_th/other", "st_sub2_main_th/tsuma", "roo_com/2a",
    "roo_com/1a+7", "roo_com/4a", "roo_com/2a+7", "roo_com/3b+7",
    "roo_com/1b+7", "roo_com/7"
  ),
  x = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8)
)

links <- data.frame(
  source = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
  target = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12, 8, 10, 11, 13, 5, 10, 17, 17, 18, 19, 2, 21, 22, 17),
  value = c(2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
)
```

I draw sankey diagram with the following scripts assuming that nodes will be aligned from left to right by following `node$x`, that is in the order of `st_con_rt`, `st_con_tr`, `st_adsb`, `st_th`, `tr_adsb`, `st_sub_main_th`, `st_sub2_main_th` and `roo_com`.

```
plot_ly(type="sankey", orientation="h", arrangement="snap",
    node = list(label=nodes$name, x=nodes$x, pad=10),
    link = links
  )
```

However, the output diagram does not follow x position specified in the script.

[image]

For instance, two elements with prefix `st_th` is now in the 3rd order whereas its position is 4th. `tr_adsb`, `st_sub_main_th` and `st_sub2_main_th` are in the same 5th position and some are in the 6th position.

I suppose it might occured due to automatic alignment based on occurance of each element thus I tried other layout parameters such as `freeform` but the result was the same.

Is there any way to fix x-axis of nodes as desired?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the only way I could get this to work is if I also provided a y coordinate together with an x coordinate. If you use snap arrangement you can set y to a fixed number and the nodes should spread out vertically until they don't overlap.

I found this quite unreliable though, it seems that if there are too many nodes at a single x position it will still occasionally move a node to the right of where it should be.

Note that your example code doesn't work, the number of rows provided for the data frames is incorrect, for both links and nodes. The below with fixed data frames might give you what you are looking for. You can vary the y position a bit to move the graph as a whole up and down but if you set it too close to 0 or 1 you might get nodes drawn off-canvas.

```
nodes <- data.frame(
  name = c(
    "st_con_rt/main-room", "st_con_rt/sub-room", "st_con_tr/direct",
    "st_con_tr/terrace", "st_adsb/add", "st_adsb/sub", "st_th/hira",
    "st_th/tsuma", "tr_adsb/add", "tr_adsb/sub", "st_sub_main_th/hira",
    "st_sub_main_th/other", "st_sub_main_th/tsuma", "st_sub2_main_th/hira",
    "st_sub2_main_th/other", "st_sub2_main_th/tsuma", "roo_com/2a",
    "roo_com/1a+7", "roo_com/4a", "roo_com/2a+7", "roo_com/3b+7",
    "roo_com/1b+7"
  ),
  x = c(0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8)
)

links <- data.frame(
  source = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15),
  target = c(2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 4, 7, 9, 10, 12, 8, 10, 11, 13, 5, 10, 17, 17, 18, 19, 2, 21, 22),
  value = c(2, 3, 5, 1, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1)
)
plot_ly(type="sankey", orientation="h", arrangement="snap",
        node = list(label=nodes$name, x=nodes$x, y=rep(0.4, length(nodes$x)), pad=10),
        link = links
)
```

It's all a bit janky but with some playing around with y values and padding I can usually get it to work the way I want to.